# Running Xcode project on simulator with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using XCode 11.5 and created a empty project integrated with cocoapods 1.10.0.

When I add some dependency, the build phase "[CP] Embed Pod Frameworks" fails with following message:

> /Users/jeferson/Projects/AwesomeProject/ios/Pods/Target Support
> Files/Pods-AwesomeProject/Pods-AwesomeProject-frameworks.sh: line 131:
> ARCHS[@]: unbound variable.

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
target 'Example' do
    pod 'google-cast-sdk', '4.4.6'
   pod 'ComScore', '~> 6.6'
end
```

Note: It works only in legacy build system

How to use run cocoapods projects on simulator?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you created the `Podfile`? Can you show us your `PodFile`?

Comment: I edited with the podfile. Its a new project from xcode default templates, I only integrated it with cocoapods.

Comment: @JefersonDaniel I'll not ask why you have to use xcode 11, you probably have your reasons. But, are you sure you're using the correct command line tools to match xcode 11?

Comment: Yes, I'm am using XCode 11 and don't have other versions installed. I'm using it at other projects with legacy buildsystem, the problem only happens when using new buildsystem + cocoapods